# Vue.js 2. Не работает v-for

Tags: vue.js

Здравствуйте!

Не работает v-for от vue.js 2

```
<div id="app" v-for="user in users" >\{{user.userName}}</div>

let app = new Vue({
   el: "#app",
      data: {
         users: [
            {userName: "A"},
            {userName: "B"},
            {userName: "C"},
         ]
      }
});
```

Выводит просто пустую строку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в jsfiddle выводит ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы корневой ноде `id="app"` пытаетесь v-for сделать, т.е. создать несколько экземпляров, она должна быть одна.
Сделайте вот так:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="user in users">
    {{user.userName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Ниже пример с компонентом (ответ на комментарий):

```js
Vue.component('user-card', {
  data: () => {
    return {
      users: [{
        username: "A"
      }, {
        username: "B"
      }]
    }
  },
  template: '<div><div v-for="user in users">\{{user.username}}</div></div'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <user-card></user-card>
</div>
```

Comment: а через template как сделать?)

Comment: Имеется ввиду псевдоэлемент `<template>`? Также:
`<template v-for="user in users">
    {{user.userName}}
  </template>`

Comment: я не правильно задал вопрос) Имеется виду через 

`Vue.component('user-card', {

  data: () => {

    return {

          users: [
               {username: "A"},
               {username: "B",
          ]
    }
},
template: '<div><div v-for="user in users">\{{user.username}}</div></div'
})`


Вот так, но если далее просто вставить селектор user-card, то опять же ничего не происходит(

Comment: Добавил пример в ответ. В комментарии выше вы зарегистрировали vue компонент, но также необходимо создать vue экземпляр и задать элемент, к которому он будет привязан.

Comment: Для примера хорошо, но компоненты лучше в отдельном месте создавать...

Comment: Спасибо) а можно еще пример импорта, если компонент в отдельном месте будет?)